# HDD semi-broken? (Cant boot)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, freeze

Last night my laptop froze on me, and i had to kill the power.
When i tried to boot up, it showed the windows logo, and stayed there for like 20 min. until it just rebooted...
I also have a Linux partition on the same disk, so tried booting to that, and it just goes black for a short time, then reboots.

I've tried  thenwindows repair thing, and its VERY slow to boot into that, but it gets there, and i ran the start-up repair. think it took like 30-40 mins, until it said that it couldn't fix the problem.

So next step i connected the disk to a USB-dock, and connected it to my other laptop.
When trying to open "My Computer" and see the disks it freezes for like 10min, then it sees my 2 partitions, but if i try to open them it just freezes and have to kill explorer...

One time it showed me some of the files, but VERY slow...

I tried starting TestDisk, but that just keep saying "Please Wait" after choosing log setting"...

Any ideas on what could have happend? or how to save my data?

```
Disk: Western Digi WD6400BEVT
Partitioned 1 for win, 1 for linux and 1 for data. (I think there might be a swap partionen for win and linux aswell)
OS: Win7 + Linux BackBox
```

Comment: I use speedfan on windows to view my SMART stats. just remember, if SMART indicates problems, that when it comes to hard disks, there is no such thing as semi-broken. mechanical hdds range from dying to not-quite-dead-yet, to dead. filesystem problems are a differant matter, but if your disk is showing mechanical failures, just get a new one, and save your data while you can. Bad blocks increase at an approximately exponential rate, so don't wait for failure before you take a good backup and migrate onto trustworthy (dying) hardware.

Comment: It will be hard for him to run any windows software if he cant even get a usable system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your disk is failing. You could attempt to connect the disk to a Linux live distro and check the SMART data on the drive. This could give you some sort of confirmation as to what is happening.

From linux you use the `smartctl` utility to check this.

Download and install the 'smartmontools' package:

`sudo apt-get install smartmontools`

Check to make sure the drive supports SMART:

`sudo smartctl -i /dev/<drive> | grep "SMART support"`

Run a test on the drive:

`sudo smartctl --test=short /dev/<drive>`

Run the report:

`sudo smartctl -a /dev/<drive>`

You can also use the Linux live distro to attempt to copy the data from the drive to another drive (thumbdrive?) in order to save you data.

Comment: Another good program for that is [badblocks](http://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks)

Comment: Definitely! The only thing that would make me think it is not just corruption is that both his windows and linux partitions are showing problems. But there would be no harm in using badblocks to make sure.

Comment: Im making a live linux usb right now, and ill try out the things

Comment: Heres the result from the smartctl test... doesnt look good..
 http://pastebin.com/ddsZpZZb .. any help using badblocks?

Answer (score 0):

If you had to cut the power while there was an incomplete write operation, it's likely that that particular area of the FS has been corrupted. I would suggest booting from a Linux Live CD to run the `fsck` command. That works for me when I need to restore Linux partitions. Once you repair your Linux, you could try to keep repairing the Windows partitions from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally recovered dozens of hard-drives using a software tool called SpinRite - https://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm you boot it via bootable CD or USB stick. I used to work at a school with many hundreds of PCs so hence how I have used it many times over the years. The software is commercial and you have to buy it, however the software author is very honest and generous in that if it does not work for you, you can ask for a full refund and he will give you your money back. Obviously it cannot recover all drives due to the many, many different factors and types of failure that can be at play, for example different physical components can fail preventing any software from reading data. But I have personally seen SpinRite recover data for me where numerous other data recovery software suites have failed. We ended up buying a site-licence at the school due to that.